# Multithread Java - synchronizing - warning Android Studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading, intellij-idea

I am using Android Studio (intelliJ-idea) for Android development. I get a warning for this piece of code:

```
    if (status == STATUS_SOLVING) {
        if (!solverThread.isAlive())
            if (status != STATUS_SOLVED) // <<<<<<  WARNING THIS LINE
                status = STATUS_DATA_COLLECTING;
    }
```

The line indicated above gives me a warning, saying that this condition is always true. I can see why this is true if the whole program runs on a single thread.

But since my program uses a parallel thread to change the value of `status`, does it not mean that this condition might change between line #1 and #3 in the snippet above?

Is this a valid warning? Am I missing something?

Do things change if I change the nested ifs into one single if with `&&` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that if you're counting on a value being changed by another thread  that's a dangerous programming tactic and that the compiler won't know that its being accessed by different friends and will optimize assuming it isn't.

Any variable that may be touched by multiple threads like that needs to be declared volatile to inform the compiler that its touched by multiple threads, and special care needs to be taken in treating it.  If you didn't know that I'll bet you have a dozen other multithreading bugs waiting to happen.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please consider answering the second part as well? Replacing nested ifs with && operator.

Comment: Won't make a difference, the compiler will optimize either way-  unless the variable is volatile, in which case it will load its value from RAM each time.  In general this is really dangerous code though-  I can see 3 or 4 race conditions just in the snippet you gave me.  If you don't have experience with multithreading and race conditions I suggest getting a code review from someone who does.

Comment: This was just an experiment... I was planning on using lock objects (synchronize(lock)). I believe this is the solution for this specific problem as I am changing the "status" based on the retrieved "status" values - therefore I will lock that segment of the code. But anyways, thanks a lot for clarification on the warning thing and bytecode optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If a second thread is involved and changes status then certainly the value can change between lines 1 and 3. Especially since you don't seem to have any kind of thread synchronization in place,  deliberate or not.
Granted, the code seems a bit unsafe, because you would not normally have two threads accessing the same variable without some kind of concurrency control. But this is speculation since I don't see the rest of your code.

Anyway, this is a warning, not an error. Sometimes warnings are wrong, that's why they can be suppressed.

You could see this as a sign that you're up to some unsafe stuff though. Perhaps you could post some more code in case you want to discuss the actual synchronization aspects?